# Android Call application

Tags: android

I am working in an application for Calling. When my application activity is on top, call should be accept from my activity and my activity always be on top if call has been received/dialed. I am working in API Level 8 rooted phone. I don't want to use default call receiver and any screen of call receiver application. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `IntentFilter`.

Read this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html